# WSO2 ESB + activeMQ

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, esb, ttl, amq

I'm new in wso2 esb and jms. I send some messages from soapUI to wso2 esb. In my wso sequence a processed message goes to the jms. Is there a possibility to set "time to live" of this message from wso2 esb? Or some other ways?

In AMQ I added this:

```
<policyEntry queue="myQueue">
  <deadLetterStrategy>
    <individualDeadLetterStrategy
      queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true" />
  </deadLetterStrategy>
```

Something like
`<property name="JMSExpiration" value="today+hour_long_value" scope="transport" type="STRING"></property>`
in sequence have no effect.

Comment: In soapUI? have you seen jms headers? Worth try it out if not.

Comment: I tryed to use a header Mediator in wso2 esb. <header name="JMSPriority" scope="transport" value="7"></header> but there's no any effect. A message received in amq still have default priority 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workable way, I found out, is to create own Mediator, which will set the time-to-live of a message and send it to the queue. The queue name is preset in a sequence, then called mediator:

```
<property xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="qname" value="your_queue_name" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>

<class xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="com.example.JMSMessageTimeToLiveMediator"></class>
```

A mediator class:

```
public class JMSMessageTimeToLiveMediator extends AbstractMediator implements
    ManagedLifecycle {

private static String CON_FACTORY_NAME = "QueueConnectionFactory";
private static String DEF_PROP_QNAME = "qname";
private static long TIME_TO_LIVE = 60000;

private static QueueConnectionFactory cf;

public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        String queueName = (String) context.getProperty(DEF_PROP_QNAME);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setTimeToLive(TIME_TO_LIVE);

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(context
                .getEnvelope().toString());

        producer.send(message);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error("ProduceJMS ERROR: " + e.getClass() + "   "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ProduceJMS ERROR: " + e.getClass() + "   "
                + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("ProduceJMS ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public void init(SynapseEnvironment emvironment) {
    Hashtable<String, Object> environment = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    environment.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
            "org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    log.debug("ProduceJMS INIT");
    try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(environment);
        cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(CON_FACTORY_NAME);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        log.error("ProduceJMS INIT ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void destroy() {
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JMS Message Store you can just set property JMS_PROD_TIME_TO_LIVE.

```
<property name="JMS_PROD_TIME_TO_LIVE" value="15000" />
<store messageStore="my_jms_message_store" />
```

Tested with WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 (with synapse version 2.1.3-wso2v11)

You can find more information in [JmsProducer code](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/store/impl/jms/JmsProducer.java)

Same way you can set for example message priority (property JMS_PROD_PRIORITY).